# No audio output in ubuntu 12.04.4 lts

Tags: sound, output

I have ubuntu 12.04 lts and my aufio output suddenly stopped! I have an HP ProBook and the audio output from the internel speakers stopped but if there are external put ispeaker then the output is perfectly fine. Is there a problem with my laptop or is this a ubuntu problem?

Answer (score 0):

- Try to use alsamixer https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/Alsamixer

  and tweak "speaker" volume , "automute" switch etc...
- Alternatively try to install and run "pulseaudio volume control" (pavucontrol) and change profile in the right tab.